# conversion from type dbnull to type string is not valid

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

im always getting this messagebox there is a blank in a column and there is time when i really dont need to include data.what should i do?

```
Private Sub dataasset()
    With assetdata
        codelbl.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
        codename.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
        codedepartment.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
        assetdescrip.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
        custodian1.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value
        serialnumber1.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value
        acquisitioncost.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value
        dateacquired1.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value
        location1.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells(8).Value
        prnumber1.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value
        purchaseorder1.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells(10).Value
        condition.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells(11).Value
        remarks.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells(12).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the given answers, I think I would like to share my "WAYS" also.

in .NET:

```
codelbl.Text = IIF(IsDBNull(.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value),"",.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value) '"" or "N/A" depending on how you want a blank data to be displayed
...
```

or to avoid that in .NET, you can use it like this in your query:

```
SELECT isnull(YourFieldStr,''),isnull(YourFieldVal,0) FROM YOUR_TABLE
```